# How to filter out empty arrays/lists in OData v4 Query?

Tags: odata

In OData V4, you are able to filter out empty strings as follows:

```
OData/v4/2.0/Case?filter=Date ne null
```

or `OData/v4/2.0/Case?filter=Date ne ''`

I, however, have an OData query which requires filtering out an empty array/list of names (empty would be: [] so an empty list). Lists cannot be filtered out in the same way:

```
OData/v4/2.0/Case?filter=Names ne null
```

does not work. Same goes for the other method.

Is there another way to filter out lists like this Names one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

...Or you can use **any()** operator.

> The any operator without an argument returns true if the collection is not empty.

[docs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc371341806)

OData/v4/2.0/Case?$filter=Names/any()

Answer (score 2):

If your service supports this operation, you can use the [`$it` literal](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc371341812):

```
OData/v4/2.0/Case?filter=$it/Names/$count gt 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The below one was working for me, hope this helps.

https://api-uk.securitycenter.windows.com/api/machines?$filter=not machineTags/any()

Am filtering out the results where the machine tags are empty array.

Comment: You are a savior !